# Emoji & Special Symbols dialog randomly takes forever

Tags: macos

The hotkey for the Emoji & Special character dialog is [Ctrl]+[Command]+[Spacebar]. Sometimes it comes up immediately. Sometimes it takes a really long time. Sometimes it refuses to show itself even when the option is available from [Edit] in the top bar.

Connected to this issue, often when I drop a character from this dialog, it might be 30 seconds to a minute before the character shows up. Or it never shows. Which stalls any other emoji from being placed for 2–3 minutes.

Here's a short list of problematic applications. There's seemingly no guarantee that these will show off the issue though.

- Atom
- Chrome's address bar
- messenger.com

[image: MacOS Emoji & Special Character Dialog]